# How to correct mistake of having allocated not enough space to the root partition (not a trivial case)

Tags: gparted, move-partition

When partitioning my hard drive (the only one I have) prior to installing Linux I made a mistake of not allocating enough space for the root partition. And now I have the following set of partitions (from left to right):

1. `sda1` - 65 GB - `/`
2. `sda2` - 5 GB - `swap`
3. `sda3` - 360GB - `/home`

The problem is that `sda1` is almost full and I need to install something that requires considerable amount of space. So, I would like to increase the size of `sda1` at the expense of `sda3` which is less than half full anyway. It is only too easy to resize `sda3` with Gparted live USB to free up, say, 35 GB which would be quite enough for any foreseeable future. But what is next? How do I merge this empty space (which would, of course, be allocated after `sda3`) with `sda1`?

P. S. I have already backed all the data up.

Comment: You're overcomplicating this.  If you shrink `sda3` using the left handle in GParted, you'll have a Gap of Free Space at between `sda2` and `sda3`.  Remove `sda2` temporarily, resize `sda1` to the desired size, and MOVE `sda3`down.  Make sure to Apply between each step(GParted will renumber the sda's but this will not affect data).  This will leave you 5GB at the end of the drive to recreate the swap.  ALWAYS PUT the swap space at the end of the drive for this exact reason.  Shrinking involves making the partition the minimum size available temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

If you shrink `sda3` you can create a new, fourth, partition, and mount that as your largest directory. For example, shrink `sda3` to 60GB and you can then mount the 300GB `sda4` as `/var` or as `/usr`, depending on your needs.

1. Shrink the partition `sda3` and also shrink the file system on `sda3`.
2. Create a new, fourth, partition, format it with your filesystem of choice, mount it as `/mnt`.
3. Copy over everything in `/var`or `/usr` over to this new partition.
4. Change `/etc/fstab`to that `/sda4` gets mounted on `/var` or `/usr` on next boot.

Comment: You mean there is no need to increase the size of `sda1`. The new partition would become a mounted part of it in stead. I see, thank you for the idea!

Comment: If you use LVM you can consider extending `sda1` with the new `sda4` but otherwise I think this method should work and be equally good.

Comment: @Tommiie usually you add entire drives as PVs into an LVM, not single partitions. But I agree that a system with LVM set up would have been easier to fix.

Comment: You can also delete current swap, edit fstab to temporarily remove mount with # & create new swap at end of drive after you shrink /home. Then update fstab entry for swap to new UUID. If old MBR partitioning you do have a 4 primary partition limit, and may need to use the extended partition which is one primary and then logical partitions.  This is where gpt is better as it has a soft 128 primary partition limit, that can even be made larger.  Have not seen anyone that needs or finds useful 128 partitions as too many to manage, but better to have option of more than 4.